# Curl working on system but not in laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I'm trying to use curl to make request through a project in laravel.

The problem is that when I run the function I get the following message:

getPage needs CURL module, please install CURL on your php.

"getPage" is the function that executes cURL.

When I want to install curl on my php I get the message that it is already installed after placing the curl command.

What happens? Is it due to an error in the composer.json? Should I reinstall php or change php.ini?

It would be very helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: install curl in your machine first, then the php extension for curl. then check it via `phpinfo()` to verify

Comment: You need to provide us with the exact function you are executing and its contents, exact commands, and their exact output. and possibly with the output of your `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` page.. Also with the command you are using to "install curl" and it's exact error..